# How to place a figure near a matrix?

Tags: tables, graphics, plot

I am looking for a way to place the figure next to the matrix, with the matrix numbered (1)
And name the figure with the corresponding graph to the matrix (Fig.1: corresponding graph of the matrix (1) ).

My attempts:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{kbordermatrix}
\begin{document}
\[ CM' ={%
   \begin{tabular}[b]{cc}
       {\(\kbordermatrix
            { &  1  &   \textcolor{red}{3} &  4 \\
            1 &  1  & \textcolor{red}{x_{13}} & x_{12}x_{24} \\
            \textcolor{red}{3}& \textcolor{red}{0} &  \textcolor{red}{1} & \textcolor{red}{x_{34}} \\   
            4 & 0 & \textcolor{red}{0} &  1  
            }
        \)%
       }

   \end{tabular}}
\]

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
      mycircle/.style={
         circle,
         draw=black,
         fill=black,
         fill opacity = 0.99,
         text opacity=1,
         inner sep=0pt,
         minimum size=12pt,
         font=\small},
      myarrow/.style={-Stealth},
      node distance=0.6cm and 1.2cm
      ]
      \node[mycircle] (c1) {\textcolor{white}{1}};
      \node[mycircle,above right=of c1] (c2) {\textcolor{white}{2}};
      \node[mycircle,below right=of c1] (c4) {\textcolor{white}{3}};
      \node[mycircle,below right=of c2] (c3) {\textcolor{white}{4}};

    \foreach \i/\j/\txt/\p in {% start node/end node/text/position
     c2/c3/$e_{24}$/above,
      c1/c2/$e_{12}$/above,
       c1/c3/$e_{14}$/below,
        c1/c4/$e_{13}$/below,
         c4/c3/$e_{34}$/below}
       \draw [myarrow] (\i) -- node[sloped,font=\small,\p] {\txt} (\j);


     % draw this outside loop to get proper orientation of 10
     
    \end{tikzpicture}
  
\end{document}
```

Fig.1: corresponding graph of the matrix (1)
The result was unsatisfactory:
[image]

I'm looking for an output like this:

[image]

Comment: Since the matrix uses display math, that is designed to take up the full text widhth. Easiest solution I can think of is to use two `minipage`s: one for the matrix and one for thte figure.

Comment: @PeterGrill Is it possible to put them inside a hidden table?

Comment: Not if you want the equation number between the two.  You will still need to add `[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]` to the tikzpicture.

Answer (score 3):

Nest the two parts in minipages.

I'd use `nicematrix` features rather than `\kbordermatrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
\vspace{-0.8\baselineskip}
\begin{equation}\label{a-matrix}
CM'=
\begin{bNiceMatrix}[
  first-row,code-for-first-row=\scriptstyle,
  first-col,code-for-first-col=\scriptstyle,
]
                   & 1                  & \mathcolor{red}{3}      & 4 \\
1                  & 1                  & \mathcolor{red}{x_{13}} & x_{12}x_{24} \\
\mathcolor{red}{3} & \mathcolor{red}{0} & \mathcolor{red}{1}      & \mathcolor{red}{x_{34}} \\   
4                  & 0                  & \mathcolor{red}{0}      & 1  
\end{bNiceMatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
\centering
\vspace{0pt}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  mycircle/.style={
    circle,
    draw=black,
    fill=black,
    fill opacity = 0.99,
    text opacity=1,
    inner sep=0pt,
    minimum size=12pt,
    font=\small
  },
  myarrow/.style={-Stealth},
  node distance=0.6cm and 1.2cm
]
  \node[mycircle] (c1) {\textcolor{white}{1}};
  \node[mycircle,above right=of c1] (c2) {\textcolor{white}{2}};
  \node[mycircle,below right=of c1] (c4) {\textcolor{white}{3}};
  \node[mycircle,below right=of c2] (c3) {\textcolor{white}{4}};
  \foreach \i/\j/\txt/\p in {% start node/end node/text/position
    c2/c3/$e_{24}$/above,
    c1/c2/$e_{12}$/above,
    c1/c3/$e_{14}$/below,
    c1/c4/$e_{13}$/below,
    c4/c3/$e_{34}$/below%
  }
  {\draw [myarrow] (\i) -- node[sloped,font=\small,\p] {\txt} (\j);}
  % draw this outside loop to get proper orientation of 10
\end{tikzpicture}

\caption{Corresponding graph of the matrix~\eqref{a-matrix}}
\end{minipage}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd prefer the caption in the middle.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
\vspace{-0.8\baselineskip}
\begin{equation}\label{a-matrix}
CM'=
\begin{bNiceMatrix}[
  first-row,code-for-first-row=\scriptstyle,
  first-col,code-for-first-col=\scriptstyle,
]
                   & 1                  & \mathcolor{red}{3}      & 4 \\
1                  & 1                  & \mathcolor{red}{x_{13}} & x_{12}x_{24} \\
\mathcolor{red}{3} & \mathcolor{red}{0} & \mathcolor{red}{1}      & \mathcolor{red}{x_{34}} \\   
4                  & 0                  & \mathcolor{red}{0}      & 1  
\end{bNiceMatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
\centering
\vspace{0pt}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  mycircle/.style={
    circle,
    draw=black,
    fill=black,
    fill opacity = 0.99,
    text opacity=1,
    inner sep=0pt,
    minimum size=12pt,
    font=\small
  },
  myarrow/.style={-Stealth},
  node distance=0.6cm and 1.2cm
]
  \node[mycircle] (c1) {\textcolor{white}{1}};
  \node[mycircle,above right=of c1] (c2) {\textcolor{white}{2}};
  \node[mycircle,below right=of c1] (c4) {\textcolor{white}{3}};
  \node[mycircle,below right=of c2] (c3) {\textcolor{white}{4}};
  \foreach \i/\j/\txt/\p in {% start node/end node/text/position
    c2/c3/$e_{24}$/above,
    c1/c2/$e_{12}$/above,
    c1/c3/$e_{14}$/below,
    c1/c4/$e_{13}$/below,
    c4/c3/$e_{34}$/below%
  }
  {\draw [myarrow] (\i) -- node[sloped,font=\small,\p] {\txt} (\j);}
  % draw this outside loop to get proper orientation of 10
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}

\caption{Matrix and corresponding graph}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: When executed I get an error message:"\l__nicematrix_last_col_in...
l.17 ]
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about "

Comment: @Emadkareem You need to update your TeX system.